# Make button enabled if checkboxes are checked in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have created a few checkboxes in a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
        {<input type="checkbox" name="check"/> @i<br>}
}
```

I also have a button called "Delete" which is supposed to delete the selected items:

```
<input type="button" id="DelButton" disabled value="Delete" />
```

For now the button will always be disabled, but I would like to know how it can become enabled if one or more checkboxes become checked.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: @Andrei I think people ask questions when they don't know how to make it their-self , otherwise what's the point of asking questions, if you can do it your self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you don't explicitly mention the use of jQuery, it does come with ASP.NET MVC by default.  So here goes...

First, respond to the change event for the checkboxes:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // respond to change
});
```

This would be invoked any time any checkbox on the page changes its state.  Then within this event handler all you want to know is if *any* checkbox is checked, right?  For that you can just select all checked ones and see if there are any.  Something like this:

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
    // at least one is checked
}
```

Then in your if/else structure you just want to enable/disable the button.  That would look something like this:

```
$('#DelButton').prop('disabled', false);
```

Putting it all together, you might have something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('#DelButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#DelButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ns5shxkz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that of `JQuery` code like this:

```
  $('.checkbox_class').change(function() {
    if ($('.checkbox_class:checked').length > 0) {
        $('#DelButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#DelButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Html code :

```
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class" />


<input type="button" id="DelButton" disabled  value="Delete" />
```

I hope to help you.

Live Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/CdwpA/1656/

Comment: The question states that there are *multiple* checkboxes, not just *one*.

Comment: The Question `one or more checkboxes become checked.`

Comment: Yes, the word "more" implies "more than one".  So the use of an `id` won't work.  And how would this logic behave with multiple checkboxes?  (Hint: It will enable/disable the button based only on the *latest* checkbox clicked, not on the current state of all of them.)

Comment: @David I Update the answer to more than one CheckBox

Comment: And your updated example no longer works.  In your jsFiddle, select two checkboxes and then de-select one of them.  What happens to the button?

Answer (score -1):

You have to initiate an event

Something like :

```
  <input type="submit" name="DelButton" class="inputButton" id="DelButton" value=" DelButton" />

  <input type="checkbox"  onchange="document.getElementById('DelButton').disabled = !this.checked;" />
```

Comment: How will this behave when there are multiple checkboxes?

Comment: @David If there is multiple checkbox , it's better to use an alternative method ,like the solution you suggested , but the user only specified that he would like to disable his delete bottom with a single checkbox

Comment: `"but the user only specified that he would like to disable his delete bottom with a single checkbox"` - You might want to take another look at the question.  Specifically the wording of "one or more checkboxes" and also specifically the *loop* in which the checkboxes are created.

Comment: @David "One or more ....." means one OR more which could be one AND could me more ........

Comment: The question *explicitly defines* multiple checkboxes.  Look at the loop at the very beginning of the question.  Under what conditions would that loop ever emit only one checkbox?  (Hint: It will *always* emit exactly 10 checkboxes.)